# What are the main differences between 'Physics machine learning work' and Mainstream Machine Learning?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have read both works from [Thermodynamics of Prediction](http://tdlc.ucsd.edu/SV2013/Bell_etal_2012_thermodynamics_of_prediction.pdf), [Optimal Causal Inference](http://csc.ucdavis.edu/~cmg/papers/oci.pdf)
and taken basic machine learning classes from computer science on prediction models, but I have yet to seen any discussion on book or forum where both topics diverge on different communities. For instance, those works were published on Physical Letters/Chaos/Entropy Journals, while mainstream conferences of Machine Learning are NIPS/ICML/KDD.

It is clear that one fundamental difference is the physics involved on the definition of the method, but I was hoping for a more clear answer which put both worlds apart. Having not obtained any conclusive answer from members of the 'mainstream Machine Learning' I was hoping this community could help me (given I do not have a Physics background).

Comment: What is "physics machine learning work"

Comment: I've seen this line of work being worded as such by computer science students on the topic. I believe it is just their way to say that the model is mapped to code, which eventually turn into a "general purpose" forecasting algorithm line regression models, decision trees, etc. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I don't think what you said answers my question. The phrase "physics machine learning work" itself is completely meaningless to me. Could you clarify what *that phrase* means.

Comment: You can consider my question reworded as 'Physics Prediction Algorithms' and 'Machine Learning Prediction Algorithms. Does this helps?